# mysql COUNT() num rows too slow

Tags: mysql, indexing

i am trying to get the number of subscribers of a user from a table which has **22m** rows.

my sql is the following:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(id)
FROM
    subscribers
WHERE
    suid=541839243781
```

which needs **12.6020 s** to load

however the following same query(gets subscriptions of a user) needs only **0.0036 s** to load(seems ok)

```
SELECT
    COUNT(uid)
FROM
    subscribers
WHERE
    uid=541839243781
```

my EXPLAIN:

```
    id  select_type     table            type   possible_keys    key    key_len     ref     rows                 Extra
     1     SIMPLE    dvx_subscribers    index        4            4       16        NULL    22041275    Using where; Using index
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE:

```
    CREATE TABLE `subscribers` (
 `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `sid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `uid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `suid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `date` datetime NOT NULL,
 KEY `id` (`id`),
 KEY `2` (`uid`,`suid`),
 KEY `4` (`suid`,`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=23226599 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

INDEXES:

```
Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name     Collation   Cardinality     Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment
subscribers     1   id  1   id  A   NULL    NULL    NULL        BTREE   
subscribers     1   2   1   uid     A   449821  NULL    NULL        BTREE   
subscribers     1   2   2   suid    A   459193  NULL    NULL        BTREE   
subscribers     1   4   1   suid    A   6115    NULL    NULL        BTREE   
subscribers     1   4   2   id  A   22041275    NULL    NULL        BTREE
```

how can i index it or optimize it to load as fast as possible? cause 12secs is hell too much for this...

Comment: Create an index on `id` and `suid`, or on `suid` alone.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar. Why `suid` alone? (Upvoted the answer where you omitted that...)

Comment: Is the 4 seconds constant or it variates?

Comment: @ypercube with the updated indexes it takes up 12 secs! the time doesnt exceed 12 seconds...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second query runs against an index `(uid)`, so it completes nearly instantaneously. The first one, however, needs to scan the table, because there is no suitable index to use. Create an index on `(suid, id)` to fix this problem.

Comment: The index should be on `suid` first, *then* on `id`.

Comment: the index seems to work on EXPLAIN but when i run it as query the SELECT takes 12 seconds... thats weird...

Comment: @fxuser This is very strange... Could you update the question with the added index and the new plan?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i have updated create table, indexes and explain.. what do you mean "new plan"?

Answer (score 0):

Since `id` can not be `NULL`, you can rewrite as:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    subscribers
WHERE
    suid=541839243781
```

Except for very recent (or future) optimizers, it should be a bit faster than `COUNT(id)`.

---

Whole 4 seconds though, sounds too slow, even for MyISAM. Perhaps the index is fragmentated.

Comment: still the same time... what do you mean fragmentated?how can EXPLAIN be very fast and SELECT take 12 secs?

Comment: `EXPLAIN` shows the query plan. It doesn't search the actual tables.

Comment: it also says that INDEXES are used, isnt this correct?why it still takes so much time?this is very weird...

Comment: The table has 23M rows. Did it have more and you deleted some (many) rows?

Comment: Can you afford to run `ANALYZE TABLE subscribers` or [`OPTIMIZE TABLE subscribers`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html) ? It may take time and all users will be locked from the table.

Comment: from analyze i got "Table is already up to date" and from optimize i didnt get anything unusual... also the time still remains the same... is 22m to much for mysql to proceed and get the rows?what else could delay the query?

Comment: Can you run `# myisamchk -dvv subscribers.MYI` from the command line and post the output?

Comment: Then it could be a configuration problem. Check your settings. [You can try this tool from Percona](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/12/23/online-mysql-configuration-wizard-from-percona/).

Comment: i did run the command but i dont know what happened? - didnt get any output